# Why are perfectly legitimate pages on my website registering in Google Webmasters as 404?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, 301-redirect, 404

I have seen this question asked several times here, but never clearly answered.

I suspect it has something to do with my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^moreinfo/(.*)$ http://www.kgstiles.com/moreinfo$1 [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^healthsolutions/(.*)$ http://www.kgstiles.com/healthsolutions$1 [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1/ [R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1/ [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

when I check the URL without a forward slash at the end, it registers as `404` (even though it renders fine in a browser), but when I write it without the forward slash at the end, it renders `200 OK`, but if I try to take off the forward slash with the `.htaccess` file, the browser gives me a `310` error (too many redirects)

you can see the `404` and `310` with this url: `http://www.kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials.html` which redirects to `http://www.kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials/` (which is a 404), so what is a solution and why might this be registering as a 404?

Any Help is appreciated!
(I'm using WordPress, BTW)

Comment: I don't get a 404 on those pages with or without the slash, nor do I get a redirect loop. Can you describe in more detail how to reproduce this?

Comment: I agree with s_ha_dum, the page itself does not appear to return a 404. However, one of your images on that page does... "http://www.kgstiles.com/wp-content/themes/Ostmosis2/images/menu-bg.png"

Answer (score 2):

The page in question (kgstiles.com/pureplantessentials/) is not returning a 404 header response. It returns a 200 response which is correct and what it should return for pages that contain content that you wish to be accessible to visitors.